# to display a value of nested list in a list on jsp

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, foreach, jstl

I am trying to iterate a list of pojos on jsp using `c:forEach` syantax.
Now the problem is that list contains a nested list ,so how should i display that aparticular value on jsp.

Here is my code on jsp :

```
<c:forEach items="${capQues.captureQuestionList}" var="captureQuestion" varStatus="status">
  <fieldset name="captureQuestionList[${status.index}].languageId" value="1">
    <legend><c:out value="${captureQuestion.languages}" /></legend>
    <div class="question"><textarea class="textarea" name="captureQuestionList[${status.index}].question" value="question"></textarea></div>
  </fieldset>
</c:forEach>
```

Where languages is also a list inside `captureQuestionList`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are missing here is the point of `var`. In your first loop `captureQuestion` will be the current object coming from the list `captureQuestionList`. You can use that reference as is, so you don't need to use `captureQuestionList[${status.index}]` to get the object. By the way, the correct syntax for this would be `${captureQuestionList[status.index]}`. So, you fieldset name can just be `${captureQuestion.languageId}`.

For loops can just be nested. For example (making some assumptions on your question object):

```
<c:forEach items="${capQues.captureQuestionList}" var="captureQuestion">
  <fieldset name="${captureQuestion.languageId}">
      <legend><c:out value="${captureQuestion.languages}" /></legend>
      <c:forEach items="${captureQuestion.questionList}" var="question">
        <div class="question">
          <textarea class="textarea" name="${question.id}"><c:out
            value="${question.value}"/></textarea>
        </div>
      </c:forEach>
  </fieldset>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that `textarea` doesn't have a `value` attribute. Put the value in it's body.

---

**Edit**: If you need to iterate over a list of languages you can use the same principle:

```
<c:forEach items="${capQues.captureQuestionList}" var="captureQuestion">
  <fieldset name="${captureQuestion.languageId}">
      <legend>
        <c:forEach items="${captureQuestion.languages}" var="language">
          <c:out value="${language.name}" />
        </c:forEach>
      </legend>
      <div class="question">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="${captureQuestion.question}"></textarea>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</c:forEach>
```

If you want to display a single language add a `c:if` to check for the language

```
<c:forEach items="${captureQuestion.languages}" var="language">
  <c:if test="${language.id eq captureQuestion.questionId}">
    <c:out value="${language.name}" />
  <c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Although it would be better to just add a reference to the right language in your model so you can just use `${captureQuestion.language}`.

Comment: Hi Japser,Thnks for your reply but the problem which i am facing is in <legend>tag i want to disaply a name of a language ,which is in list named language in captureQuestion...In short i mean  captureQuestion contains list of languages  and languages list contains name of languages ,,,so how should i print the name of a language.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Japser thnks for your prompt reply.Its working fine as you had said.Your help is really appreciated.